# How to make user information available to all controllers and their methods in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to spring and trying to develop a very basic application with database interaction.I want to know how to make user information available to all controllers and their methods as long as the user is logged in?? I am using spring mvc.

Comment: use HttpSession to store user information when user logged in.

This helps to understand what is session 
[link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668153/what-is-session-in-java

Comment: Yes,i have done this using httpSession.setAttribute. Then in the required functions i have used httpSession.getAttribute,which is fetching me the desired output. However my problem is in these functions there is something like this @ModelAttribute("userDetails") UserFormbean userDetails to support the Jsp's. Now due to the presence  of two form backing objects i am unable to edit,update the info. what should be done??

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security can help here. One the user logs in, you can access the user principal like this:

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
Authentication auth = context.getAuthentication();
User user = (User) auth.getPrincipal();
```

Comment: what will be the output for this??just the login id and pwd or all the details?

Comment: The user principal is arbitrary. By default I think `auth.getPrincipal()` just returns a string (I don't recall for sure), but you can implement and register your own custom user service to return whatever kind of `User` object you like. It might have a username, first name, email, whatever you want.

Comment: Here's a DZone RefCard I did on this: http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/expression-based-authorization